# Display SOAPUI TestRunner Response in Java

Tags: java, automated-tests, soapui

I am using SOAP UI API from Java. I have created my SOAP Project and added a Test Suite and Required Test Cases and Test Steps. I am just wondering is there any way getting the response of test in XML format? Because I want to use this data further in my tests

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.support.PropertiesMap;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCase;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestSuite;
import org.junit.Assert;
import java.util.List;
public class SoapUITest
{
  public final static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:\\WebService\\WebServiceTest\\src\\main\\java\\weather.xml");
    List<TestSuite> testSuites = project.getTestSuiteList();
    for (TestSuite testSuite: testSuites)
    {
        System.out.println("Running Test Suite: "+ testSuite.getName());
        List<TestCase> testCases = testSuite.getTestCaseList();
        for(TestCase testCase:testCases)
        {
            System.out.println("Running Test Case: " + testCase.getName());
            TestRunner testRunner = testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);
            Assert.assertEquals(TestRunner.Status.FINISHED,testRunner.getStatus());

            //Exception in the below line
            //System.out.println(((MessageExchange)testRunner).getResponseContent());
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Testing finished successfully");
  } 
}
```

I have added this code `System.out.println(((MessageExchange)testRunner).getResponseContent())`  But for obvious reason I am getting the below Exception. Not sure whether I am using the right method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange
at VMSSoapUI.main(SoapUITest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Did some one already implemented this way of sending the request and getting the response in XML format from SOAPUITestRunner?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should run a `test step` in order to expect a response of it. However, `test case` is run in your case. So, loop through the test steps.

Comment: Could you please provide me code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Code snippet for? looping thru test steps? or accessing the response?

Comment: Just running a particular step and capturing the response. I am not finding the right methods

Comment: Please see #15 of [this](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html) helps. Note that it is in groovy to run a step.

Comment: Rao, thanks for your quick response. Looks like it is in Groovy. But I need it in Java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102555/discussion-between-vikram-and-rao).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below `runStepAndGetResponseContent` *method* will run the test step and get the *response as string* for `wsdl request test step` type, which I believe, is the one you looking for. And you may add conditions for other instances of test step types as needed.

```java
public String runStepAndGetResponseContent(WsdlTestCaseRunner runner, TestStep testStep) {
        TestStepResult result = runner.runTestStep(testStep);
        if (result instanceof WsdlTestRequestStepResult) {
            return ((WsdlTestRequestStepResult) result).getResponse().getContentAsString();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Along with the above new method, below line of code of yours needs to be replaced with below code:

**Existing:**
`TestRunner testRunner = testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);`

**Replace with:** this will loop thru the test steps of a test case.

```java
WsdlTestCaseRunner runner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner((WsdlTestCase) testCase, new StringToObjectMap(testCase.getProperties()) );
for(TestStep testStep: testSteps){
      //calling the above get method here
      String response = runStepAndGetResponseContent(runner, testStep);
      System.out.print("Received response is :" + response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rao, Appreciate your effort. Its working smooth. I got the XML Response and I can do Further processing.